# Can metal strapping between floor joists be removed for ductwork?

Tags: framing

Ductwork is being installed in the basement of a two story colonial. The HVAC installer cut the cross metal strapping in joist bays where a supply duct needed to be run. Is this compliant with code?

Comment: Never seen that type for blocking of joists, but just one joist bay should not cause problems.  The other joists on each side will do the job.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Perhaps I used the wrong terminology and it should be called "metal cross bridging"?

Comment: Me too.  One bay should not be important.

Comment: The original metal strapping appears to be being ued to hold up insulation. Not structural at all. This strapping used to be called perforated metal hanger strapping and was generally used by plumbers to support pipes (water suppy and drain piping)

Comment: No, the metal strapping is an older style of bridging/bracing; it's not for insulation.  I agree that a single bridge probably isn't a problem, and if you really need the peace of mind you could probably just use a single piece of blocking between the joist bottoms, or something like this: https://www.clarkdietrich.com/products/tradeready-floor-joist-blocking

Comment: @Huesmann, instead of the cross bracing, focus on a joist. A metal strap from one side braces the joist from moving away from the brace's anchorage at the other end. A metal strap from the other side braces the joist from moving in the opposite direction. If you cut a strap, then its joist is free to move away from that strap's anchorage. A flat joist-to-joist strap below the cut brace restores the restraint by using a single adjacent brace for 2 joists instead of just 1. You could double up those outer braces in line with such a strap if you doubt a single brace is good enough for 2 joists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the image it's not perfectly clear, but I'm pretty confidant that the metal straps have been used as joist bracing. This is somewhat unconventional. The International Residential Code (IRC) calls for blocking above points where joists bear on top of supports. Additionally, if your floor joists are taller than 2×12, [IRC R502.7.1](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P1/chapter-5-floors#IRC2021P1_Pt03_Ch05_SecR502.7.1) calls for "bridging" like yours every 8 ft. If your joists are 2×12 or shorter, then your missing bracing is still IRC conformant.

Technically the National Design Specification (NDS--the engineering code behind the IRC) has simplified design prescriptions if you brace 2×10 and 2×12 joists at 8 ft intervals. See 4.4.1.2 from Chapter 4 of the [NDS](https://awc.org/publications/2018-nds/). If your joists are 2×10 or taller and were designed under the NDS (instead of taken from IRC tables), then the bracing could be structural. If there are multiple lines of bracing at 8 ft intervals or less, then this scenario is pretty likely. If there's just a single line of bracing at midspan, then this scenario is still a non-trivial possibility. Under the NDS, 2×8 joists and shorter require blocking at the ends but no bracing.

The metal bracing is interesting in that it only carries tension. For bracing types like blocking that carry compression and tension if the blocking is toe nailed, removing a single block leaves functional bracing from the other side. For redundant bracing like this I believe that you could theoretically remove every other brace and remain code conformant, but I would expect difficult arguments (plural) with a building official or home buyer. For metal bracing like yours, however, there's no redundancy. Installing a flat piece of metal bracing below the duct would restore the joist bracing integrity. There's already a duct supporting strap nearby that serves the bracing purpose in addition to its duct supporting purpose. My OCD might compel me to move that duct support directly in line with the bracing, but the current configuration is structurally fine even if those joists are 2×10 or taller.

Comment: Great answer with sources and details! The joists are 2x10 so based on your answer no bracing is actually required (if I understand correctly). I also added another image to the original questions showing the clearest shot of the bracing itself (not the adjacent bay but nearby)

Comment: @Nate, I'm a little nervous about this answer (not your particular situation, given that duct supporting strap). It's very common to see braced 2×10s. Such bracing stiffens the floor by distributing point loads better to multiple joists, so hopefully that's the rationale behind all of the bracing that I've just now claimed is unnecessary. If you go into the code behind the IRC, the NDS, it has a simplified design for 2×10s and taller braced every 8ft. If I'm correct, then the IRC has implemented the complex analysis for 2×10s and 2×12s, and that makes me nervous.

Comment: @Nate, fearing that my floor joists were designed under the NDS by an engineer (instead of getting spec'ed by somebody reading IRC tables), I would restore bracing for 2×10s and taller, especially if the bracing was spaced at 8ft intervals or less. Like I said, though, I believe that your duct strap has already restored the bracing. I don't like multipurpose stuff like that because 20 years later somebody could ignorantly remove that strap. My mental model of future remodelers is no basis for prescribing additional work, however. Once work is done, I accept it if it's good enough.